# MongoDB query is very slow (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, performance

Im using NodeJS and MongoDB to process my data.
Im trying to count the data corresponding to a specific geolocation that has one of a few tags.
Upon processing my queries via NodeJS and MongoDB I get this response from my MongoDB:

> 2017-07-10T18:09:55.212+0200 I COMMAND  [conn23] command
>   tweetdb.coll command: count { count: "coll ", query: { lat: { $gte:
>   70, $lt: 71 }, lon: { $gte: 67, $lt: 68 }, tag: { $in: ["foo", "bar"] } } } planSummary: IXSCAN { lat: 1, lon:
>   1, data: 1 } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:0 numYields:0 reslen:44
>   locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount:
>   { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query
>   104ms

This tells me, that my query took 104ms to finish, right? However, if I execute it in the Mongo-Shell (with the same parameters and the same data and while running the other queries, too) it takes 0-1ms.
I do happen to shoot quite a few requests at MongoDB, however, since "numYields" equals 0 this shouldnt be a problem should it? Esp. since the query I fired via Mongo-Shell worked perfectly fine even though I fired it while the other queries were still running.

Can anyone enlighten me why this problem occurs (and might even be able to tell me how I could solve it)? If further information is required I'll be happy to provide it as best as I can.